# How to switch partner portal users on the same partner account?

Tags: partner-portal

At one of our Partner's, the contact person, of which the partner license was active on is leaving.

I need to grant partner access to a new contact for that account, but all rules/groups/etc needs to stay in tact.

When trying to "disable the partner access" for the contact:

[image]

A pop up tells me that all will be deleted (there is no detail of what exactly is going to be lost)

[image]

So - how do I grant a new contact for that partner to be able to : access and see all the "historical" info/accounts/contacts/opptys/etc ?

And Account/Contacts/Cases/oppty ownership - that should be done automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you activate new contacts under the same account they will most likely get the same access as the user you are deactivating, and I say most likely because I don't know the details of the sharing settings in your organization but what you are planning to do is the standard way of doing it.

BTW, you don't really need to disable this user, you could simply deactivate the user.

Comment: I am new to this partner portal but my question is why to disable the current user as we can reuse it for the new user by editing the required filds.

Comment: Renaming users is a bad practice, one of the reasons is that it would make impossible to run accurate historical reports.